# How to use a different formatter on Highcharts in each curve of the same graphic?

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts and i want to use a different formatter for the numbers displayed in the tooltip, for each curve in the same graphic.
Thank you

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944699/can-i-use-two-different-formatters-for-highchart-tooltips for a proper solution

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to store your series tooltip text. You can do it using the following example:

```
.
.
.
series: [{
    'name': 'serie 1',
    'data': serieData, // use your array of data
    'tooltipText': 'text 1' // text which will be inside the tooltip
}]
.
.
.
```

Then you have to get your tooltip text inside the serie tooltip.

**Not shared tooltip**:

```
tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    formatter: function() {
        return this.series.options.tooltipText + '<br>' + // return stored text
                'Value: ' + this.y;
    }
}
```

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/PtYtf/1/)

**Shared tooltip**:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var tooltip = '';
        for(var i = 0, length = this.points.length; i < length; i++) {
            var point = this.points[i];
            tooltip += point.series.options.tooltipText + '<br>' +
                    'Value: ' + point.y + '<br>';
        }
        return tooltip;
    }
}
```

**[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/PtYtf/3/)**