# Can I use two different formatters for highchart tooltips?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts table with two data series that use named values. In my tooltips for one series, I want to reference a data point from the series. So the solution in this answer: [How to use a different formatter on Highcharts in each curve of the same graphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325638/how-to-use-a-different-formatter-on-highcharts-in-each-curve-of-the-same-graphic) doesn't help me. I need more than just tooltipText, I need a formatter:

For one:

```
formatter: function() {
    return this.x + ': ' + this.series.name +
    '<br> $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
     }
```

And for the other:

```
formatter: function() {
    return 'In ' + this.x + ' the median value was' + this.median + 
    'and the total $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);                        
 }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inside formatter `this` reffers to the focused serie, you can add an `if/else` inside the formatter and return a string for each one, like the following.

```
tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    formatter: function() {
        var text = '';
        if(this.series.name == 'MSFT') {
            text = this.x + ': ' + this.series.name +
                   '<br> $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
        } else {
            text = 'In ' + this.x + ' the median value was' + this.median +
                   'and the total $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PtYtf/10/)

Comment: +1, thanks - though in my opinion, it's better to use `this.series.options.id` instead of `this.series.name` so it does not rely on something that might easily change. The id can be set when initializing the series.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily define a toolip formatter for each series - see here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.tooltip

```
{
  tooltip: {
          shared: true
  },
  series: {
     name: 'some series name',
     data: mydata,
     tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' bar'
     }
  }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/28qzg5gq/

Comment: That is not a formatter, it's just suffixes. Adding a formatter in the config object of only one series must be done via the `pointFormatter` function - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/28qzg5gq/12/).

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example. The fiddle example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/tooltip/formatter/):

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + '</b>';

                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    s += '<br/>1 USD = ' + this.y + ' EUR';
                });

                return s;
            }
        },
```