# Highcharts chart.tooltip.formatter overriding series.tooltip.pointFormatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

My approach is configuring a chart with a certain tooltip-format:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    tooltip: {
            formatter: function () { return 'Default Format ...';  }
    },
    ...
}
```

... and for certain series, i need to specify a modyfied formatter:

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function () { return 'Custom Format...'; }
    }
  }, 
  ...
]
```

So this does not work, because, as i figured out, the chart-tooltip-formatter always overrides the pointFormatter of the series configuration. You can try this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8sLfuab9/1/), if you comment out the charts tooltip-configuration.

I would expect a way to set a "default" tooltip-configuration over the formatter-function for the whole chart and the possibility to override this for certain series. Is there a way to do so?

I found a few approaches like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944699/can-i-use-two-different-formatters-for-highchart-tooltips), but i need a more general apporach than if-elseing series names within the formatter function. i also want to be able to modify values, so attributes like 'valueSuffix' dont get me very far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how this override happens, but as you mention the `tooltip.formatter` takes precedence. Instead of using `tooltip.formatter` move the same function to `plotOptions.series.tooltip.pointFormatter`. This should work as you expect, with the `plotOptions` `pointFormatter` being used in general and your `series` `pointFormatter` being used in the specific cases.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8sLfuab9/3/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        tooltip: {
            pointFormatter: function () { return 'Default ' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';  }
        }
    }
},

series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormatter: function () { return 'Custom Format...'; }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

to avoid the overwrite you need to use option headerFormat for the chart tooltip and define point format for the individual series

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.headerFormat

the syntax is a bit different but at least it provides basic formatting options

let's say you want custom date format and manipulate font size and color,

your code should look like this:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '',
        xDateFormat: '%a, %b %e at %l:%M %p',
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 500; color: #8995a0;">{point.key}</span>',
    },
    ...
}
```

... and for certain series, specify a modified formatter:

```
series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter: function () { return 'Custom Format...'; }
    }
  }, 
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain a chart's formatter function to a point formatter function in certain cases, [as per this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-conditional-default/). The fiddle has a formatter with a conditional clause that 'falls through' to the default formatter:

```
formatter: function (tooltip) {
    if (this.point.value === null) {
        return 'Null';
    }
    // If not null, use the default formatter
    return tooltip.defaultFormatter.call(this, tooltip);
}
```

The Highcharts default formatter will then call any custom point formatter you have set.